# Query regarding the order of an element in the centralizer.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I was reading a text where they describe the structure of non-abelian order $12$ groups, I quote a part of the text.

"Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $12$. Let $P_3$ be a
Sylow's $3$-subgroup.

We assume that $P_3 \unlhd G$, so that $P_3 = \{1, x, x^2\}$ is the unique $3$-Sylow of $G$ and $x, x^2$ are the only elements of order $3$ of $G$.
Then $G$ acts by conjugation on $P_3$, so $|G : C_G(x)| ≤ 2$, since
cl$(x) \subset \{x, x^2\}$. Thus $C_G(x)$ has order $6$ or $12$. In either case there is a
$y \in C_G(x)$ of order $2$, then $a = xy$ has order $6$. Let $N = <a>\unlhd G$ (it is normal
because it has index $2$)."

The part I don't understand is why there is an element with order $2$ , again quoting: "In either case there is a $y \in C_G(x)$ of order $2$"

$C_G(x)=\{a\in G|ax=xa\}$

cl$(x)=\{x^a|a\in G\}$

By the way, they then assume that $P_3$ is not normal, and fill in the structure.

Comment: Every finite group of even order has an element of order $2$.